# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Access to undeclared static property: Get_category::$arr in /opt/lampp/htdocs/IRIS/controllers/get_category.php:9

Tags: php, arrays, xml, undeclared-identifier

I keep getting the error listed above in the title. In a class called Get_category I am trying to access a static array called $arr from a class called Categorize.

Here is the Get_category class where I am trying to access the array:

```
  class Get_category extends Controller{
         function run($xml){
         global $FILE_ROOT, $STORAGE, $REQ_ID, $CMD_EXTRA, $LIB, $BIN;
         include_once __DIR__.'/categorize.php';
         $file = $xml->filename;
         $arr = Categorize::$arr;
         /*$arrlength = count($arr);*/
     $arrlength = max(array_map('count',self::$arr));
         $response = "<parameters>\n<requestID>" . $REQ_ID ."</requestID>\n<requestType>get_category</requestType>";

         for($i = 0; $i < self::$arrlength; $i++){
         $lengthcolumn = count(self::$arr[$i]);
            for($j = 0; $j < $lengthcolumn; $j++){
                if(self::$arr[$i][$j] == $file){
                echo self::$arr[$i][$j];
                $response .= "<resource><id>" . self::$arr[$i][$j] . "</id>";
        $response .= "</resource>";
                }

            }

         }

        $response .= "</parameters>";

        return $response; 

         }

}
```

Here is the Categorize class where the static array is located:

```
     class Categorize extends Controller{
       public static $arr = array();
       function run($xml){
              global $FILE_ROOT, $STORAGE, $REQ_ID, $CMD_EXTRA, $LIB, $BIN;

              $numCategories = intval($xml->numCategories);
              self::$arr;
              /*self::$arr = array();*/

              /*if(!pe($xml, "resourceList")) die(err("No resources found"));*/

              for($i=0;$i < $numCategories; $i++){
                  $name = intval($xml->nameCat);
                         if($i=0){
                            self::$arr[0][0] = $name;
                         }else{
                            self::$arr[$i][0] = $name;
                         }

              }
              $j = 0;
              while($j < $numCategories){
                  $numDoc = intval($xml->numDoc);
                       $k = 0;
                       foreach($xml->resourceList->resource as $res){
                                  self::$arr[$j][$k] = $res;
                                  $k++;
                       }
                   $j++;         
              }
             $output = "Done!";
             $response = "<parameters><requestType>categorize</requestType><requestID>". $REQ_ID . "</requestID><resourceList>". $output . "</resourceList></parameters>";

             return $response;
       }
}
```

Comment: The use of `global` isn't particularly good, either pass the values around as parameters or pass them into the constructor of the class.  `global` makes it difficult to test and dependency injection gives much more flexibility.

Answer (score 0):

In your Get_category class, you should not be referring to your local variables as static class members. In other words your class should look like this:

```
class Get_category
{
    function run($xml)
    {
        global $FILE_ROOT, $STORAGE, $REQ_ID, $CMD_EXTRA, $LIB, $BIN;

        $file = $xml->filename;
        $arr = Categorize::$arr;
        /*$arrlength = count($arr);*/
        $arrlength = max(array_map('count', $arr));
        $response = "<parameters>\n<requestID>" . $REQ_ID . "</requestID>\n<requestType>get_category</requestType>";

        for ($i = 0; $i < $arrlength; $i++)
        {
            $lengthcolumn = count($arr[$i]);
            for ($j = 0; $j < $lengthcolumn; $j++)
            {
                if ($arr[$i][$j] == $file)
                {
                    echo $arr[$i][$j];
                    $response .= "<resource><id>" . $arr[$i][$j] . "</id>";
                    $response .= "</resource>";
                }
            }
        }

        $response .= "</parameters>";

        return $response;
    }

}
```

With all references to self::$arr and self::$arrlength changed to $arr and $arrlength